# Type MyComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppSharedModule and AppSharedModule

Tags: angular

I just recently encountered an interesting situation.  I am using Angular v4.1.3.  I have a component called MyComponent that is declared and exported in my AppSharedModule.  I am  importing the AppSharedModule in the main AppModule and 2-3 other feature modules.

What confuses me is the error message I get (**Type MyComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppSharedModule and AppSharedModule**).  It almost seems that the app sees 2 instances of AppSharedModule.

Has anyone seen this error message?  Am I missing anything?

Here is my code:

AppModule:

```js
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppSharedModule } from './app-shared.module';

import { ConfigService } from '~/app/services/config.service';
function configServiceFactory(config: ConfigService) {
    config.loadPhone();
    return () => config.load();
}


//components
import { AppComponent } from '~/app/components/app.component/app.component';
import { CurrentApplicationsComponent } from '~/app/components/currentApplications.component/currentApplications.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [        
        AppSharedModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule        
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        CurrentApplicationsComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        ConfigService,
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: configServiceFactory,
            deps: [ConfigService],
            multi: true
        },
    ],
    exports: [

    ],
    entryComponents: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

AppSharedModule:

```js
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BlockUIModule } from 'ng-block-ui';
import { ToastyModule } from 'ng2-toasty';

...

//helpers
import { MyComponent } from '~/app/helpers/myComponent.component';

...

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        BlockUIModule,
        ToastyModule.forRoot()        
    ],
    declarations: [        
        MyComponent,
        ...
    ],
    providers: [
        ... 
    ],
    exports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,        
        BlockUIModule,
        ToastyModule,
        MyComponent,
        ...
    ]
})
export class AppSharedModule { }
```

Comment: if you're using the CLI, can you try to kill it and re-serve? Sometimes it can get 'confused' if you're changing modules.

Comment: Thanks @joh04667.  That worked.  Weird.